# Suit up with a ...?

Tags: grammar

For a party, the dress code is formal dress with an element in pink.

On the flyers, I want to write "**Suit up with a pink touch**" but somebody told me it is not correct and advised "suit up with a touch of pink" but I'm not sure.

What do you think ?

Thank you

Comment: I'd be more concerned about 'suit up' than anything else. Still, if you think your readers will know what it means, then it's fine.

Comment: What do you propose instead ? I though it was fun with the how i met your mother reference but again, if it is not correct, I can change. English is not my mother language.

Comment: Difficult to propose an alternative, because I don't know what it means. I'm afraid I don't understand 'how I met your mother reference' either.

Comment: In that TV series, their is a character always saying "suit up" to ask others to put a suit. It is quite popular among students (targeted public).

Comment: Never heard of it, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think *formal with a dash of pink* is what you want, unless you think every single person on the invite list will understand the "How I Met Your Mother" reference.

Comment: Concurring vote here.  I prefer either "_dash of pink_" or "_touch of pink_" over "_pink touch_"

Comment: This also has the advantage of being gender neutral. I don't think you expect the women attending to wear suits, do you?

Comment: The women should wear suits and the men should wear pink!